# How to make a text event call on a function and how to display images in AS3?

Tags: image, actionscript-3

Originally the AS3 script would trace some words for a certain string I typed in the textfield (**ti**). I want to know how to display and image, instead.

I know in AS2 it was loadMovie but I don't know how to do this in AS3. And would the **loadit** in the **newvid** function be the movieclip that changes or something else? (O got that **function newvid** script off a website.)

```
ti.border = true
ti.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);

function onInput(event:TextEvent):void {
    if(ti.text.search('happyface')!=-1) newvid;
    else if(ti.text.search('sadface')!=-1) trace ('sadface.jpg');
}

function newvid() {
    var loadit = new Loader();
    addChild(loadit);
    loadit.load(new URLRequest("happyface.jpg"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Loader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary) class lets you load another SWF or Image file. Once loaded your loadit object becomes another display object. You can fix it's position, hide/show it or listen to it's events. Following is a very comprehensive example of using Loader class

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/

Also check out the example in Loader documentation for [example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Answer (score 0):

imho you need the [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class, you should add a listener

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
loader.load(new URLRequest("norton.swf"));

private function onInit(e:Event):void {
   addChild(loader.content);
}
```

Comment: what would the onInit function be? and how to I access loader.content?